# Validate Input Radio for Jquery not working value checked

Tags: jquery, validation, input, radio-button

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="produtoListaDescTamanho">
  <label class="textoPadrao pequeno laranja"><input type="radio" name="tamanho-324" value="9"><b>Frango Teriaky R$ 6.00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></label>
  <label class="textoPadrao pequeno laranja"><input type="radio" name="tamanho-324" value="8"><b>Camarão R$ 6.00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></label>
  <label class="textoPadrao pequeno laranja"><input type="radio" name="tamanho-324" value="7"><b>Salmão e Queijo Qualho R$ 6.00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></label>
  <label class="textoPadrao pequeno laranja"><input type="radio" name="tamanho-324" value="6"><b>Salmão R$ 6.00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></label>
  <label class="textoPadrao pequeno laranja"><input type="radio" name="tamanho-324" value="10"><b>Mignom R$ 6.00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></label><br><br>
 </div>
```

and this Jquery not working for validate is input radio with Jquery, var tamanho = undefined. Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.produtoAddCarinho').live("click",(function(){    
  alert(this.id);
  var tamanho = $('tamanho-324:checked').val(); // or $('input[name=tamanho-'+this.id+']:checked', '#tabela_geral').val();
  var produto = document.getElementById('desc-'+this.id).innerHTML;       

  if (tamanho == undefined)
  {
    $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Selecione o tamanho, para adiconar o produto <br><br>" + produto );
  }
  else
  {
    Inserir(this.id, tamanho, produto);        
  };
  temp = document.getElementsByName('tamanho-'+this.id);
  $(temp ).removeAttr('checked');
  $(temp ).attr('previousValue', false);
}))});
```

tks

Comment: `live` is deprecated use `on` instead..

Comment: Try `$('input[name="tamanho-'+this.id+'"]:checked')` (i.e., add double-quotes around the value of the name attribute).

Comment: The element `<tamanho-324>` doesn't exist. Your selector is wrong. Use `input[name='tamanho-324']` instead

Comment: This has nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Thanks.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use name selector in jquery.

```
var tamanho = $('input:radio[name="tamanho-324"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repalce   

temp = document.getElementsByName('tamanho-'+this.id);
$(temp ).removeAttr('checked');
$(temp ).attr('previousValue', false);


with

$('#tamanho-'+this.id ).each(function( index ) {
this.removeAttr('checked');
this.attr('previousValue', false);
});
```